# Alias CD to a directory that's name is included in current directory

Tags: command-line, alias, cd-command

I've been using cmake and creating a build folder for my cmake code and I want to easily cd to the build directory.  I've been naming my build directory in this format:

/parent/codeandsuch

/parent/codeandsuch_build

I've tried the following alias in my bashrc but its not working. Ive copied the name of the current directory to a string, added _build to it and tried to cd but its not working.  Any ideas? Thanks

```
alias cdbuild='DIR=${PWD##*/} || DIR = DIR + "_build"|| echo DIR || cd ../DIR'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't concatenate strings with `+` in bash. Also you need to prepend a `$` to the variable name to use its value. So, instead of:

```
DIR = DIR + "_build"
```

use:

```
DIR="${DIR}_build"
```

The whole thing becomes:

```
alias cdbuild='DIR=${PWD##*/} || DIR="${DIR}_build || echo "$DIR" || cd "../$DIR"'
```

Alternatively:

```
alias cdbuild='cd "$(pwd)_build"'
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it.  The alternative also is much more elegant than what I was trying